# can wcf netTcpBinding callbacks return out of order

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

Consider a most simple client/server callback setup using `netTcpBinding`

Server:

```
_callback.BeginReceive(message, EndCallbackClient, null);//send message to client
```

Client :

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
public class TradingClient : ITradingClientCallback, IDisposable
{
      public void Receive(Message message)
      {
            //handle message
      }
```

Please note `<reliableSession ordered="true"/>` is *not* in the WCF config

If, for example, the client side froze for a moment and a number of messages were sent from the server **could the client `Receive` them out of order?**

I have attempted to simulate this but have been unable to reproduce a scenario where they are out of order, however I had a random application error previously that indicated it might have happened.

Intuitively thinking about how sockets work I would have said this isnt possible but having a look at the client-side message callback reveals lots of code:

[image]

I know the messages are being sent in the correct order server-side and I know that if written to the socket in order they will be read off the socket in the correct order client-side - however as indicated by the red arrow theres lots of WCF code after the async socket read that I'm wondering if 2 (or more) messages read off the wire could result in out of order messages at the app level.